# CPU: Older Technique + higher benchmark scores vs newer technique + lower scores

Tags: laptop, performance, cpu

I am searching for a new laptop. I've noticed that the newer `i5-6200U` (Skylake) is beaten by a `i7-4700HQ` (Haswell). Why does Intel produce lesser Skylakes with a high price instead of producing only the Haswells which perform better? Even with new techniques (Skylake > Haswell), the Haswell performs better. Why?

Comment: One is an i5, the other is an i7. The i5 is also pretty low in the series if the number is anything to go by. There could be a lot of differences between the processors besides the tech refresh.

Comment: This looks like a product recommendation at this time. Please see the [help/on-topic] and [ask] for more and edit your question.

Comment: i5, i7...these are just names

Comment: @user2945914 no, they distinguish the various performance levels expected. An i7 is the enthusiast performance chip, the i5 is midrange, while i3 is budget range. The numbers then futher separate  performance levels.

Comment: It's the same with graphics cards, a GTX 780 can easily beat a GTX 930 even though it is an older processor

Comment: You’re comparing a ultra-low power CPU (“U”) with a high performance quadcore CPU (“HQ”). Unless there is a very significant generation or technology gap, the results are very obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [Intel ARK](http://ark.intel.com/compare/88193,75116) website's compare feature you can get this table:

```
Name                         i5-6200U  i7-4700HQ
►# of Cores                  2         4 
►# of Threads                4         8 
►Processor Base Frequency    2.3 GHz   2.4 GHz 
►Max Turbo Frequency         2.8 GHz   3.4 GHz 
►TDP                         15 W      47 W 
►Recommended Customer Price  $281.00   $378.00
```

You can see that the `i7-4700HQ`, even though it is older, it has double the cores and threads, a higher base and turbo frequency and a higher TDP. This puts it solidly ahead of the `i5-6200U`. It's MSRP is also ~$100 more than the `i5-6200U`.

Comment: you mean the TDP is the point?

Comment: @user2945914 More important is that it has 2x the cores and threads and the clock speeds are higher.